# Debugging Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(name) in an external assembly with decompiled symbols

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I am debugging an external Microsoft assembly which makes a call to `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(name)` to get an embedded resource.

This returns `null` the first time it is executed as I step through with the debugger. However, when I run it afterwards in the Visual Studio `debugger watch` it returns the `Stream` object for the resource successfully.

When I run it in the watch before execution, it also returns null. Ie it only works after I step through to execute the line in the actual code and then run it in the watch.

When it I use typeof to get the assembly it also works even before execution, as in `typeof(class).Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream()`.

**Limitation**
I am using `decompiled symbols` to debug the external code so I'm facing some limitations in the debugger, for example I can't step backwards.

**Practical issue**
The external assembly fails to load the embedded resource as a result.

You can let me know if there's any more information you need.